# Multiple instance of jQuery plugin in Angular tabs using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've made a custom jQuery plugin myself that creates a calendar.
In my Angular app I have multiple tabs, and each one should contain a calendar instance.

view.html

```
<tabset>
<tab ng-repeat="bien in biens" active="$last" >
    <div id="calendar_{{bien.ID}}" >
        <frontcalendar model-id="{{bien.ID}}"></frontcalendar>
    </div>
</tab>
```

so I've made a directive :

```
frontApp.directive('frontcalendar', function ($parse) {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: 'views/calendar.html',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

          launchCalendar(attrs.modelId);

      }
  };
});
```

in views/calendar.html there is

```
<div class="calendar_container" id="calendar_container_{{bien.ID}}"></div>
```

And my jQuery plugin launchCalendar simply does

```
$("#calendar_container_"+id_div).html(some_generated_html);
```

When I log the DOM in my jquery plugin it doesn't seem to find the #calendar_container_{{ID}}...

Where am I failing ?

Answer (score 0):

diff your **bien.ID** in AngularJS and **id_div** in javascript

I can't resolve this problem because you didn't give sufficient data.

Comment: Ah sorry, id_div in my jQuery plugin is the parameter passed to launchCalendar